# Given a file with 10 million integers between 1 and 1000, how would we print them in sorted order in Java? Looking for some effcient way.

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures

Total number of Integers = 10 million
Range of Integers = 1 - 1000

So, it is clear that integers are not unique. How can we print them in sorted order ?
Should we use bit vector or ASCII Array or some other DS ? What is the best way to do this ?

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way to do this is to first determine the number of times each integer in the allowed range appears in the array.

```
int[] data = ...
int[] counts = new int[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    counts[data[i] - 1]++;
```

You can then iterate across the `counts` array and print the corresponding integer the correct number of times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++)
{
    int count = counts[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(i + 1);
}
```

This strategy is O(n) time.